# Determine the equation of a line that passes through point $A(1,0,2)$ and intersects the line $r=(-2,3,4) +s(1,1,2)$, at a right angle.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Vector/Linear algebra question. I already have the solutions manual but I still don't understand how to arrive at the answer. Would appreciate some help, thank you. $r$ is a vector equation for a line by the way.

Comment: First think about a line that goes through the point of interest ($(1,0,2)$) and some point on the other line. There are lots of lines like this, one for each point on the given line. Then you need to find the one that is perpendicular to the given line.

Comment: I'm still not completely clear.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a plane perpendicular to the line is
$$x+y+2z=a$$ if it passes through $(1,0,2)$ then $a=5$.
Now the intersection of $x+y+2z=5$ with the line is given when
$$-2+s+3+s+2(4+2s)=5$$
or $s=\frac{2}{3}$ so now we just take the line through these two points.

Comment: I've been trying to go off of what you and Mhenni said but I still don't fully understand. Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: I usually like to use projections for these types of problems, but this is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The directional vector $u=(a,b,c)$ of the line is perpendicular to the vector

> $$ v=(1,1,2), $$

which is the directional vector of the line $(-2,3,4)+s(1,1,2)$. To find $u$ then solve the system which is resulted from the dot product

> $$ (1,1,2).(a,b,c)=0 $$

Comment: You mean $(1,1,2)\cdot (a,b,c) = 0$. $(-2,3,4)$ is not the directional vector.

Comment: @Braindead: Yes you are right. It is a typo. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

A parametric equation of a line is given by the formula:

$f(s) = p + v s$

Here, $p$ is some point on the line and $v$ is a vector pointing in the direction of your line.

You are trying to find an equation of the line that has the following properties:

1. The line goes through $(1,0,2)$.
2. The line is perpendicular to $(-2,3,4) + s(1,1,2)$.

The first condition gives you a point on the line. So you can make $p = (1,0,2)$.

The second condition, at least in theory, tell you how to get the vector $v.$

Rather than giving you the answer to the problem you posted, which seems like a homework assignment, I will perform essentially the same problem with different numbers. Apply the steps I am taking to your problem, and you should be able to get a solution that works.

---

Determine the equation of a line that passes through point $A(0,2,1)$ and intersects the line $r=(2,-3,-4)+s(-2,1,1)$, at a right angle.

As I said before, equation of a line is given by $l = p + v s$, where $p$ can be ANY point on your line.

My problem specifies that the line goes through $(0,2,1)$. So it makes a lot of sense to make $p = (0,2,1)$.

This is only half of the problem, as we need to determine what $v$ is. Whatever $v$ is, it must be perpendicular to line $r=(2,-3,-4)+s(-2,1,1)$. (See picture.)

[image: Description of the Problem]

Now, pick a random point on the line $r=(2,-3,-4)+s(-2,1,1)$. You can literally choose ANY point. Let's call this point $R$ ("R" for random). You can pick a point by choosing ANY value of $s$.

You can pick $s = 0, 1, 2, 3\dots -1, -2, -3\dots$ or even a fraction or an irrational number. But the easiest one to choose is $s=0$, so let's go with that.

$r(0) = (2,-3,-4) + 0 (-2,1,1) = (2,-3,-4)$. So let's call this point $R = (2,-3,-4)$

In the picture, you should see a picture of a right triangle formed by $A(0,2,1)$, your random point $R=(2,-3,-4)$, and $S$, the point where our line would intersect the original.

Now, observe that the vector $A(0,2,1) - R(2,-3,-4) = (-2,5,5)$ is essentially the hypotenuse of our triangle. Let's call this vector $h = (-2,5,5)$ (blue arrow)

The base of the triangle is in the direction of the line, which is given by $(-2,1,1)$ (shown as the green arrow). As the picture shows, we don't really know if $(-2,1,1)$ makes up one of the sides of the right triangle, but it is certainly along the right line.

To find the side of the triangle that is along $(-2,1,1)$ (shown as the red arrow), we can perform a procedure called orthogonal projection.

$$\mathrm{Proj}_w v = \dfrac{v\cdot w}{w\cdot w} w,$$

where $v\cdot w$ means the scalar product.

What it does is that it finds a "shadow" of one vector onto another one. In this situation, we can take $A(0,2,1) - R(2,-3,-4) = (-2,5,5)$, the hypotenuse (blue arrow), and project it onto $(-2,1,1)$ (green arrow), and this will give us exactly the base of the triangle (red arrow).

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Proj}_{(-2,1,1)} (-2,5,5)&= \dfrac{(-2,5,5)\cdot (-2,1,1)}{(-2,1,1)\cdot (-2,1,1)} (-2,1,1)\\
&=\dfrac{(-2)(-2)+5(1)+5(1)}{(-2)(-2)+(1)(1)+(1)(1))} (-2,1,1)\\
&=\dfrac{14}{6} (-2,1,1)\\
\mathrm{Proj}_{(-2,1,1)} (-2,5,5)&=\dfrac{7}{3} (-2,1,1) = (\frac{-14}{3}, \frac{7}{3}, \frac{7}{3})\\
\end{align}

Now, we have a vector $w = (\frac{-14}{3}, \frac{7}{3}, \frac{7}{3})$ on the base (red arrow in the picture.) We have our hypotenuse vector $h = (-2,5,5)$ (blue arrow). The third side of the triangle is then just the difference of $w$ and $h$ (not pictured).

\begin{align}
 w - h &= (\frac{-14}{3}, \frac{7}{3}, \frac{7}{3}) - (-2,5,5)\\
&= (\frac{-14}{3}, \frac{7}{3}, \frac{7}{3}) + (2,-5,-5)\\
&= (\frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3})
\end{align}

By construction, you should be able to see that $(\frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3})$ is a **possible** candidate for $v$. Because it is perpendicular to our original line: $r=(2,-3,-4)+s(-2,1,1)$.

So one possible equation is: $l = A + v s = (0,2,1) + (\frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3})s$

Now, emphasized that $(\frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3})$ is a **possible** candidate, because ANY multiple of this vector points along the same (or opposite) direction.  $(\frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3}, \frac{-8}{3}) = \frac{-8}{3}(1,1,1)$, so this vector points in the opposite direction as $(1,1,1)$, but this will still give you the same line.

So another possible equation is: $l = A + v s = (0,2,1) + (1, 1, 1)s$

Another possible equation is: $l = A + v s = (0,2,1) + (2, 2, 2)s$

Another possible equation is: $l = A + v s = (0,2,1) + (-2, -2, -2)s$

Etc.

I like: $l = A + v s = (0,2,1) + (1, 1, 1)s$

Now here is a final check.

1. $l$ goes through $(0,2,1)$? Yes, it happens when $s=0$.
2. Is $l$ perpendicular to $r$? Use the dot product to see if we get zero. (Zero dot product means perpendicular):

$$(-2,1,1)\cdot(1, 1, 1) = -2 +1 +1 = 0$$